# Eclipse Compare Editor: Ignoring "$Id:" Lines

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, diff

When I do a comparison of two projects in Eclipse, I basically get a list of every single file in the project. This is usually because the two are either A.) from a different repo or B.) checked out a different times.

Is there a way to setup the Compare Editor to ignore lines containing "$Id:"? I would even be open to an alternative Comparison Editor module if it were stable.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a way to do that in eclipse. There is an unfixed [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=36436) in Eclipse about this.

There are external comparators which have the ability to ignore differences based on regex: [meld](http://meldmerge.org/), [kdiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), [compare it!](http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3.htm), [beyond compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly what you are looking for : try this

```
Windows -->> Preferences -->> General -->> Compare/Patch
```

Under General Tab, you can configure the "member names that should be excluded from Compare with each other".

Am using Eclipse Galileo.